# Error in running spring boot application in localhost

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, tomcat, console.log

I am a beginner at spring boot and I cannot my spring boot application on the server.  I used tomcat server and IDE as eclipse. I want to run my app in browser.
My console is here

```
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.1)

2021-01-14 09:36:34.144  INFO 14508 --- [           main] com.example.demo.FirstApp1Application    : Starting FirstApp1Application using Java 15.0.1 on DESKTOP-TCH1T7S with PID 14508 (E:\springboot\FirstApp1\target\classes started by Samanthika in E:\springboot\FirstApp1)
2021-01-14 09:36:34.160  INFO 14508 --- [           main] com.example.demo.FirstApp1Application    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-01-14 09:36:35.384  INFO 14508 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-01-14 09:36:35.397  INFO 14508 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-01-14 09:36:35.397  INFO 14508 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
2021-01-14 09:36:35.507  INFO 14508 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-01-14 09:36:35.508  INFO 14508 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1283 ms
2021-01-14 09:36:35.730  INFO 14508 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-01-14 09:36:35.842  WARN 14508 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistration org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistration.setUseLastModified(boolean)'
2021-01-14 09:36:35.843  INFO 14508 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-01-14 09:36:35.846  INFO 14508 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-01-14 09:36:35.864  INFO 14508 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-01-14 09:36:35.879 ERROR 14508 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:
   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.addResourceHandlers(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:339)

The following method did not exist:

    'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistration org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistration.setUseLastModified(boolean)'
The method's class, org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistration, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/Samanthika/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.2.12.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ResourceHandlerRegistration.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistration: file:/C:/Users/Samanthika/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.2.12.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistration
```

this is my pom.xml file. hera I have added two dependencies apart from default web dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>FirstApp1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FirstApp1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>       

        
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here the FirstApp1Application.java class

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FirstApp1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FirstApp1Application.class, args);
        System.out.println("Welcome");
    }

}
```

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController {
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome")
    public static String Welcome(){
        return "Welcome to spring boot";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: How did you create this application? Which versions of the various Spring libraries is it using?

Comment: spring-boot-starter-web : 2.3.7.RELEASE and spring-webmvc: 5.2.12.RELEASE

Comment: @SamanthikaRajapaksa The first line of your console output is literally this: `:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.1)`. 2.4.1 is the Spring boot version, check my answer and fix the dependencies in your pom, it will be ok.

Comment: You shouldn't have `spring-webmvc` as a dependency, that already comes through `spring-boot-starter-web`. Generaly speaking these kind of errors come from mixing jars/modules from different versions of a framework (in those case either Spring or Spring Boot). If you want help to fix that, add your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` to the question.

Comment: Using Mavens DependencyManagement may help here.
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you are using incompatible modules. This is also what the error message says:

> Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a
> single, compatible version of
> org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistration

In order to fix this go to https://start.spring.io/ and generate a project based on your needs. For an "MVC project" you only need `spring-boot-starter-parent` and `spring-boot-starter-web`; you definitely should not bring in webmvc, here's an example pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I have added all the classes of my code and pom.xml file.

Comment: @SamanthikaRajapaksa Posting your pom definitely helps, now we don't need to guess. The answer you accepted is still not the real solution for your issue, you don't need `spring-boot-starter` and you definitely don't need `spring-webmvc`, delete those as well since they can cause issues. Take a look at the pom in my answer, `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-test` are the only dependencies you need.

Answer (score 2):

Just try to remove the version tag from spring-boot-starter-web dependency and remove the spring-webmvc dependency from pom.xml file.

Removing the version tag from this dependency.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistration org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistration.setUseLastModified(boolean)'

Based on the above line, you didn't annotate the class with @Component, IOC can't register that been

Comment: So are you saying that [`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html) is not thrown because that particular method does not exist but because a bean is missing?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense nor is it hardly an answer. The bean is there, it is just a different version, coming from the fact that the OP mixes modules from different versions of Spring/Spring Boot.